# How do I view / edit FBX animations in python? using py-fbx

Tags: python, sdk, autodesk, fbx

I'm looking to edit or create new animation data from a FBX file, downloaded from mixamo,

untill now, I found the py-fbx library, I also found the documentation but its only for c/c++ and I'm having a tough time translating(?)

My goal is, to view / edit the animation data from a fbx file, say I downloaded a humanoid animation from mixamo, and for it, I want to change the animation data for the 'HEAD' or something or completely remove it.

docs: http://docs.autodesk.com/FBX/2014/ENU/FBX-SDK-Documentation/index.html

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Python, but there is a simple workround, one can use threejs fbx loader `import { FBXLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader";` to load the 3d model to a threejs scene, then the animation is simply a threejs `AnimationClip` object, which can be easily convert to a json file. Then you can modify the quaternions/vectors for the bones.